# What code can potentially disturb existing jquery/CSS of a page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a online presenation with [Reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/)

By default,the content are positioned in the middle of the screen.I downloaded the source code,made my presentation in notepad in my computer and it was perfect.But ,when i put the presentation online on my website,the contents are centered horizontally,but not vertically.

Inspite of the source code being exactly the same,the output is different.Here is [output](http://derpina.ilovetrolls.org/2013/02/test.html). The contents are not vertically centered.I tried manually putting

```
    <div style="position: absolute;      
     top: 50%"
         >text</div>
```

But the output is nowhere near 50%...(it comes somewhere around top:40px,left:50px approx(some unrelated wierd position)

Any troubleshooting tips?

The strange thing is when i copy paste the source code i used in notepad in my pc and pasted it online,the output is different.

Here is the working code of http://jsfiddle.net/uSGe4/.

the contents are by default vertically centered.but when i paste the exact same code on blogger,the contents are not verticallye centered. http://derpina.ilovetrolls.org/2013/02/test.html#/

Comment: Can you please post the code that works so we can compare?

Comment: Thanks a lot http://jsfiddle.net/uSGe4/

Comment: omg! it works fine in http://jsfiddle.net/uSGe4/ too.....but when i put it in blogger.here http://derpina.ilovetrolls.org/2013/02/test.html#/

The contents are not vertically centered.

Comment: Obviously the container you are putting it in has its own styles/heights that interfere with where Reveal.js needs to be placed. Have you tried eliminating various outer elements to see what is causing the conflict?

Comment: but i dont have any css other than that of reveal.js on the enitre page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
    .reveal.center,.reveal.center .slides,.reveal.center .slides section{
            min-height:auto!important
    }
```

seems to work after that